# How to send AT commands via ADB Shell on Android 10 device

Tags: android, adb, at-command

I have Roco K706 head unit, I am Connect that device adb via wifi port.
That device have a lte 4g sim card support and Main point is here.
I want to send some At commands via adb shell. But i dont find which device id is true…

here some device list from my adb shell.
[image]
[image]